# InvalidArgumentError logits and labels must be same size: logits_size=[3215,25] labels_size=[10,25]

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, softmax

I was having quite a few errors (OOM, shape problems, etc) which I had managed to fix somehow.

But I'm unable to get my head around this error. I have searched quite a bit and I have also tried the sparse cross entropy with logits method in tensorflow and the tf.squeeze function also but that also didn't help me in resolving this error. Here is the link of the code (it's a github gist with the entire stacktrace and errors).

[Code Link](https://gist.github.com/blaine12100/3b57754722b1055d17883f0748734194)

Here is the link for the data set(It's around 500 Mb)

[Dataset Link](https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/deep-learning-challenge-1/identify-the-objects/a0409a00-8-dataset_dp.zip)

Here is the Code (just in Case):

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import glob
from numpy import array
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder,OneHotEncoder
import h5py
import tensorflow as tf

def loading_saving_image_as_grayscale_train(img):
    ##combined_path='M:/PycharmProjects/AI+DL+CP/test_img'+img
    loading=Image.open(img)

    loading=loading.resize((28,28),Image.ANTIALIAS)

    loading=loading.convert('L')

    #loading.show()

    conversion_to_array=np.asarray(loading,dtype=float)

    train_data.append(conversion_to_array)


def loading_saving_image_as_grayscale_test(img):
    #combined_path = 'M:/PycharmProjects/AI+DL+CP/train_img/' + img
    #print(combined_path)
    loading=Image.open(img,'r')

    loading=loading.resize((28,28),Image.ANTIALIAS)

    loading=loading.convert('L')


    conversion_to_array=np.asarray(loading,dtype=float)

    test_data.append(conversion_to_array)

import os
import requests, zipfile, io
import pandas as pd
#url = requests.get('https://he-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/media/hackathon/deep-learning-challenge-1/identify-the-objects/a0409a00-8-dataset_dp.zip')
#data = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(url.content))
#data.extractall()

#os.listdir()

dataframe1=pd.read_csv('test.csv')
dataframe1.index=dataframe1.index+1
only_index=dataframe['image_id']


test_data=[]
train_data=[]



train=glob.glob('train_img/*.png')
test=glob.glob('test_img/*.png')


#other=loading_saving_image_as_grayscale('M:/PycharmProjects/AI+DL+CP/test_img/test_1000b.png')

#print(Image.open('M:/PycharmProjects/AI+DL+CP/test_img/test_1000b.png'))
#print(test)

#loading_sample=Image.open('M:/PycharmProjects/AI+DL+CP/test_img/test_1000b.png')

#loading_sample.show()
#print(train)
#print(test)
for data in train:
    #print(data)
    loading_saving_image_as_grayscale_train(data)

for item in test:
    #print(item)
    loading_saving_image_as_grayscale_test(item)

#print(train_data)
#print(test_data)

'''with Image.fromarray(train_data[1]) as img:
    width,height=img.size
    print(width,height)
'''
def OneHot(label,n_classes):
    label=np.array(label).reshape(-1)
    label=np.eye(n_classes)[label]

    return label
dataframe=pd.read_csv('train.csv')
train_data=np.asarray(train_data)
test_data=np.asarray(test_data)
uni=dataframe['label']

dataframe1=pd.read_csv('test.csv')
dataframe1.index=dataframe1.index+1
only_index=dataframe['image_id']


label=LabelEncoder()
integer_encoding=label.fit_transform(uni)
#del uni
#del dataframe

#print(integer_encoding)

binary=OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
integer_encoding=integer_encoding.reshape(len(integer_encoding),1)
onehot=binary.fit_transform(integer_encoding)

train_data=np.reshape(train_data,[-1,28,28,1])
test_data=np.reshape(test_data,[-1,28,28,1])
#onehot=np.reshape(onehot,[-1,10])

train_data=np.transpose(train_data,(0,2,1,3))
test_data=np.transpose(test_data,(0,2,1,3))

train_data=train_data.astype(np.float32)
test_data=test_data.astype(np.float32)

print(train_data.shape,test_data.shape,onehot.shape)

graph = tf.Graph()

with graph.as_default():
    # placeholders for input data batch_size x 32 x 32 x 3 and labels batch_size x 10
    data_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 28, 28, 1])
    label_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[None, 25])

    # defining decaying learning rate
    global_step = tf.Variable(0)
    decay_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(1e-4, global_step=global_step, decay_steps=10000, decay_rate=0.97)

    layer1_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 1, 64],stddev=0.1))
    layer1_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[64]))

    layer2_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 64,32],stddev=0.1))
    layer2_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1,shape=[32]))

    layer3_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([2, 2, 32, 20],stddev=0.1))
    layer3_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1,shape=[20]))

    layer4_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([20,25],stddev=0.1))
    layer4_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1,shape=[25]))

    layer5_weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([25, 25], stddev=0.1))
    layer5_biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[25]))



    def layer_multiplication(data_input_given):

        #Convolutional Layer 1

        #data_input_given=np.reshape(data_input_given,[-1,64,64,1])

        CNN1=tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(data_input_given,layer1_weights,strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME')+layer1_biases)

        print('CNN1 Done!!')

        #Pooling Layer

        Pool1=tf.nn.max_pool(CNN1,ksize=[1,4,4,1],strides=[1,4,4,1],padding='SAME')
        print('Pool1 DOne')

        #second Convolution layer

        CNN2=tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(Pool1,layer2_weights,strides=[1,1,1,1],padding='SAME'))+layer2_biases
        print('CNN2 Done')
        #Second Pooling

        Pool2 = tf.nn.max_pool(CNN2, ksize=[1,2,2,1], strides=[1,2,2,1], padding='SAME')
        print('pool2 Done')
        #Third Convolutional Layer

        CNN3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(Pool2, layer3_weights, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')) + layer3_biases
        print('CNN3 Done')
        #Third Pooling Layer

        Pool3 = tf.nn.max_pool(CNN3, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
        print('Pool3 DOne')
        #Fully Connected Layer
        Pool4=tf.nn.max_pool(Pool3,ksize=[1,2,2,1],strides=[1,2,2,1],padding='SAME')

        FullyCon=tf.reshape(Pool4,[-1,20])

        FullyCon=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(FullyCon,layer4_weights)+layer4_biases)

        print('Fullyconnected Done')
        dropout = tf.nn.dropout(FullyCon, 0.4)

        dropout=tf.reshape(dropout,[-1,25])

        dropout=tf.matmul(dropout,layer5_weights)+layer5_biases

        #print(dropout.shape)


        return dropout


    train_input = layer_multiplication(train_data)
    print(train_input.shape)

    loss = (tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=label_placeholder,logits=train_input))
            + 0.01 * tf.nn.l2_loss(layer1_weights)
            + 0.01 * tf.nn.l2_loss(layer2_weights)
            + 0.01 * tf.nn.l2_loss(layer3_weights)
            + 0.01 * tf.nn.l2_loss(layer4_weights)
            )
    #other=(tf.squeeze(label_placeholder))

    #print(tf.shape())

    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(name='Stochastic', learning_rate=decay_rate).minimize(loss,global_step=global_step)

    #print(train_input.shape)


    batch_size = 10

    num_steps=10000

    prediction=[]

    with tf.Session(graph=graph) as session:
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
        print('Initialized')
        for i in range(num_steps):
            print("in loop")
            offset = (i * batch_size) % (onehot.shape[0] - batch_size)
            batch_data = train_data[offset:(offset + batch_size), :, :]
            batch_labels = onehot[offset:(offset + batch_size), :]

            print("training")
            feed_dict = {data_placeholder: batch_data, label_placeholder: batch_labels}
            _, l, predictions = session.run(
                [optimizer, loss, train_input], feed_dict=feed_dict)
            print(sess.run(tf.argmax(label_placeholder, 1), feed_dict={x:test_data}))
            prediction.append(sess.run(tf.argmax(label_placeholder,1),feed_dict={x:test_data}))
            print('Finished')

    submit=pd.Dataframe({'image_id':only_index, 'label':prediction})
    submit.to_csv('submit.csv',index=False)
```

I also had a doubt regarding predicting class labels. Can someone tell me whether the method I'm using for storing the predicted class labels will work or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reshape operations do not make sense:

```
FullyCon=tf.reshape(Pool4,[-1,20])
```

this will collapse batch dimension and feature dimensions.

Why would output of Pool4 have 20 dimensions? The fact it has 20 kernels does not mean it has 20 dimensions. Dimensionality is 20 * size of the image on this level of convolutions, which will be **much bigger** (my guess is it will be 6430).

It should be something among the lines of

```
output_shape = Pool4.shape[1] * Pool4.shape[2] * Pool4.shape[3]
FullyCon=tf.reshape(Pool4, [-1, output_shape])
```

and then you will have to change final layer accordingly (to match shapes).

Comment: Will try this solution today.Any tips on how should i reshape the last layer properly so as to avoid this error?

Comment: For the last reshape operation,do i have to do as you have done above(the one with[-1,25])?

Comment: The suggestion is in the answer - you should be able to read out Pool4 shapes, and that what you need for reshape.

Last reshape is actually redundant, your tensor should be of this size already before hand, if it is not, then something is wrong in previous lines.

Comment: OK.Will try this later.I tried to modify the reshape part yesterday but i am still getting the same logit error.The last shape(Dropout) is (3215,25) which is of the form(Dataset_size,labels) but logits expects it of the form (batch_size,labels).This is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error has been fixed after reshaping everything properly and also in the softmax with logits part,i had to send the data_placeholder for logits.After doing this the issue got cleared.